# how to add product's tags in the prestashop 1.7

Tags: admin, prestashop-1.7

I am sorry for the nub question but where I can add tags into product. Prestashop 1.7 software.
in their docs it should be simple http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Tags but I dont see them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When editing the product, it's in the Options tab.
Add them seperated by a comma, like they mention.

Edit:
I was trying on a 1.7 local installation and it looks like they have a bug. They are not a "language field", and do not save the input.

Edit2:
It's not very intuitive, but if someone whats to use only one tag, it still needs to input the comma. Or on other words, it's not separated by a comma, but a comma after every word. then it will save.

Comment: after a better look, I saw it is a language field, but still doesn't save on my installation.